# How to avoid cleanup function been called when didmount in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function, which should be called in unmount. But it will call when the first mount.
Is there any way to solve this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function App() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount");
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {modal && <Modal />}
      <button onClick={() => setModal(true)}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

my code pen link: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-gareth-ww9fi?file=/src/App.js:0-394

Comment: It is not called, the issue is that `Modal.js` is empty so when clicking to the button it breaks the app and that time `unmount` callback is called. https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-keller-5ne4d?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: your code above is the way to execute code while the component unmounts using useEffect i.e returning  a function from the function passed to useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an empty array `[]` as the second argument to useEffect.

The effect gets cleaned up and rerun on every render unless you provide an array of dependencies. Passing an empty array will cause it to run only on mount and clean up only on unmount.

Answer (score 0):

You see `unmount` in your console because you have error when `Modal` component is mounted. In your codesandbox link when the error shows your `App` component was unmounted.
And the reloading of codesandbox every time also remounts your component when you change it.